# Change the div location run time

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a form page with multiple input fields and a drop down field at the top of form.
condition is when dropdown value change some fields location will change..
example:
With dropdown value 1 form will be.

```
Name ____  
Address ____  
PAN No ____  
Mobile ____
```

And with dropdown value 2 form will be.

```
Name ____  
Mobile ____   
Location ____  
PAN No ____
```

link [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eapO5t3sJyFCptSbPZc7?p=preview)

Comment: not clear what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

You can try an approcah similar to this.

Declare an `array` of fields you want to show, initially keep that `array` empty and on `change` of dropdown based on `value` populate the `array` with the desired fields, bind your `UI` to that dynamic `array`.

something like :-

```
$scope.inMod = ["Noda1", "Noda2" ];
$scope.stack = []; //initially the stack has no items, empty UI
$scope.selectedNoda = ''; //this makes sure nothing show up
$scope.nodaChange = function(value){
    if(value=='Noda1') {
         $scope.stack = ['Name', 'Address', 'PAN No', 'Mobile'];
    }
    if(value=='Noda2') {
          $scope.stack = ['Name', 'Mobile', 'Location', 'PAN No'];
    }
}
```

and iterate on the `array` in `UI`

```
<select ng-model="selectedNoda" ng-change="nodaChange(selectedNoda)" ng-options="x for x in inMod">
</select>
<div ng-repeat="item in stack">
  <label>{{item}}:</label>
  <input id="item" type="text" ng-model="item" />
  <br /> 
</div>
```

Comment: @gifpif yes i know, that was just a prototype, you can bind a different `model` object